# Ошибка Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Config\Cfg' not found in

Tags: php, php7

Выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Config\Cfg' not found in
>   W:\domains\iwexal-framework\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in W:\domains\iwexal-framework\index.php on line 5

Использую OpenServer
PHP-7.0
Apache-PHP-7

Файл: **index.php**

```
<?php

use Config\Cfg;

$cfg = new Cfg;
var_dump($cfg->get('database'));
```

Файл: **Cfg.php**

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use Core\Module\Config\Config;

class Cfg extends Config
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->add_cfg('database');
    }
}
```

Файл: **Config.php**

```
<?php

namespace Core\Module\Config;

class Config
{
    public $_stack = array();

    function get($key)
    {
        return (isset($this->_stack[$key])) ? $this->_stack[$key] : NULL;
    }

    function add($key, $value = null)
    {
        if ($value != null)
        {
            $this->_stack[$key] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function reqfile($name_file)
    {
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Config/cfg/' . $name_file . '.php';

        if(file_exists($path))
        {
            $items = require_once $path;

            if(!empty($items))
            {
                return $items;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new \Exception(
                    sprintf('Config file <strong>%s</strong> is not a valid array.', $path)
                );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new \Exception(
                sprintf('Cannot load config from file, file <strong>%s</strong> does not exist.', $path)
            );
        }

        return false;
    }

    function add_cfg($name_f)
    {
        $item = reqfile($name_f);

        add($name_f, $item);
    }
}
```

**Структура проекта**

[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: Прежде чем использовать класс, его нужно подключить через `require` или `include`

Comment: Дополню ArchDemon, либо использовать composer.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, напишу сейчас класс для подключения классов.